# REM units in Stroke-width on high density displays

Tags: html, css, svg

The issue I'm having is that I **think** it might be a bug and am unsure if it is.

Basically when You have a stroke width = 1 rem, the browser takes the root font size and multiplies it by the screen density ratio like so:

On most PCs and so on:

```
ratio: 1
html font size: 14px
svg stroke width: 1rem => 14px * 1 = 14px
effective pixel stroke width => 14px * 1 = 14px
```

And there it works well.

On mobile the ratio is higher so:

```
ratio: 2
html font size: 14px
svg stroke width: 1rem => 14px * 2 = 28px
effective pixel stroke width => 28px * 2 = 56px
```

So the effective stroke is double than expected.

https://codepen.io/sivael/pen/eYmGZpW

Codepen here.

The codepen consists of two semitransparent rectangles. They overlap on PC but on mobile the SVG bar is wider.

Is this intended or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: When you say "mobile" what do you mean? The pen looks okay in Chrome for Android.  I'm guessing maybe you are testing with Safari on iOS?  IIRC Safari has or did have various bugs with rem units.

Comment: Ah, yes I was using stock samsung browsers which both seem to have this issue while chrome doesn't. Thanks for the pointer! (I thought samsung browsers *were* chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes **it's a bug**.

It turns out that Paul LeBeau pointed me in the right direction - this problem is replicable in stock Samsung browsers but NOT in the Chrome browser on the same devices.

Thus:

Some browsers (even if they share a common base) will have certain bugs and this is one of them, so be aware of that when using REM units in SVG on mobile :)